# More notification center keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, notifications

I know there is a system wide keyboard shortcut to open the notification center and once opened you can navigate your notifications with the up/down buttons on your keyboard.

But is there also a way to dismiss/delete/mark-as-read the selected notification with a keyboard shortcut?